# Django forms with ajax, what would be the best approach?

Tags: ajax, django, django-forms

I am building a plataform inspired on LinkedIn design. I have my pagination made with ajax, when the user scrolls down the page load texts and information which I want them to be editable.

The user will be seeing his information, but when he hovers the info he will see an edit icon, if he clicks all that information becomes an editable form.

What would be the best approach for building it? Do you suggest using some form library? Until now I am using django built in forms.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you explained is much more related to your client (browser) and just a little to your backend django code running on the server. The backend can handle your data and it can also render pages for you, but if you want fancy dynamic stuff running in the browser you need tools that work there.

There are plenty of frameworks available e.g. [vue.js](https://vuejs.org/), [react](https://facebook.github.io/react/) or [angularjs](https://angularjs.org/) to name a few.